# Disable automatic screen view events in Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

i would like to disable the automatic screenview tracking of firebase. Since i only want to manually log screenviews.

I work with flutter and am currently trying to solve the problem for android.

I already placed the following setting within the < application > tag of the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

But i still get screen_view events in various situations. F.e. when i start my app:

```
V/FA      (11488): Logging screen view with name, class: /, Flutter
```

Whose syntax in the terminal looks strangely different than the other events f.e. when someone start the tutorial:

```
D/FA      (11488): Passing event to registered event handler (FE): tutorial_begin, Bundle[{ga_screen_class(_sc)=Flutter, ga_screen_id(_si)=-402319410397233698, ga_screen(_sn)=/}]
```

How can i disable the automatic screenview tracking?

Comment: Did you fix it? I'm having the same problem even after adding the <application> tag.

Comment: No, sadly not. Where you able to solve the problem?

Comment: No, I think it's still a problem with analytics for flutter.

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the issue on the latest Analytics SDK? I believe there has been a reported issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2225) similar to the issue you encountered, and it seems like it has already been resolved.